# Can I make a C++ program in Notepad then compile and run it in Command Prompt?

Tags: c++, compilation, notepad

How would I do this if it is possible?  Would it work the same way with Notepad++?

Comment: Can't tell whether you're trolling or not. A C++ program needs to be [compiled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) using a [C++ compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_compiler#C.2B.2B_compilers) before you can execute it. You can write it using Notepad or whatever text editor you want. Anyway, your question is off-topic. I suggest you start with a beginners [book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks).

Comment: Not sure it's off-topic, two of the four FAQ entries seem to apply: "software tools commonly used by programmers" and "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession".

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838659/useful-notepad-plugins-for-c-c-developement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you would need a compiler of some sort. C++ *source* code won't just run, you need to turn it into an executable file.

And, yes, you can easily do this. If you download [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (minimalist GNU for Windows), you can compile source code from the command line just fine, using any editor you want to create the source files.

But it's possibly not something I'd inflict on a beginner, you may want to look in to the Microsoft Visual Studio Express editions since they give you an IDE which makes you life easier, unless you're a crusty old coder like me who still likes using punched cards :-).

Answer (score 0):

Like others mentioned, You just need a compiler to compile a C++ code and then execute it (if the compilation is free of errors). It is NOT dependent on what platform you use to write your code - any text editor works. Notepad or any other editor is just a tool.

Answer (score 0):

You need a compiler to execute the code(e.g, gcc(use cygwin to run gcc if your on Windows)). Also, please search first before you ask(there are a lot of info on the Internet about C++ compiling). I suggest Visual Studio if you want to compile without using the command line(and make programming easier)